# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool' with np.select

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'` when trying to use np.selelct with the below code.

```
condition = [(tt_df.loc[tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] <=1000])
,(tt_df.loc[tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] > 1000] & tt_df.loc[tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] <=2000]),
,(tt_df.loc[tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] > 2000])]

replace = [1000, 2000, 3000]

df['model_value'] = np.select(condition, replace, default = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of boolean masks insted list of filtered DataFrames by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'RATING_BASE_AMT':[4,1000,999,1001,2000,2001],
})
```

Convert values to numeric:

```
tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] = tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'].astype(float)
```

Or if possible some non numeric values in column:

```
tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] = pd.to_numeric(tt_df['RATING_BASE_AMT'], errors='coerce')
```

---

```
replace = [1000, 2000, 3000]
condition = [(df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] <=1000), 
             (df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] > 1000) & (df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] <=2000),
             (df['RATING_BASE_AMT'] > 2000)]

df['model_value'] = np.select(condition, replace, default = 1)
```

Or use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['model_value1'] = pd.cut(df['RATING_BASE_AMT'], 
                          bins=[-np.inf, 1000, 2000, np.inf], 
                          labels=[1000, 2000, 3000])

print (df)
   RATING_BASE_AMT  model_value model_value1
0                4         1000         1000
1             1000         1000         1000
2              999         1000         1000
3             1001         2000         2000
4             2000         2000         2000
5             2001         3000         3000
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael. still getting the same error.  They are float64 now.

Comment: @Jordan - oops, problem was something else, edited answer.